# Sagemaker Tensorflow 2.0 endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, endpoint, tensorflow2.0

I have a tensorflow 2.0 model I would like to deploy to an AWS sagemaker endpoint. I have moved the model to S3 bucket and executed the following code, but get below error because there is no TF 2.0 image. If I try to deploy with different version (e.g. 1.4, 1.8) I get ping time out errors.

Is it possible to create one easily? I can't find a good tutorial to follow. Or will Amazon deploy one at some point.

Failed. Reason:  The image '520713654638.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/sagemaker-tensorflow:2.0-cpu-py2' does not exist..

```
    from sagemaker.tensorflow.model import TensorFlowModel
    sagemaker_model = TensorFlowModel(model_data = 's3://sagemaker-eu-west-1- 
    273649867642/model/model.tar.gz',
                                  role = role,
                                  framework_version = '2.0',
                                  entry_point = 'train.py')

    %%time
    predictor = sagemaker_model.deploy(initial_instance_count=1,
                                   instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge')
```

Also no images seem to support python 3 even though they suggest you define that when setting up the model.

"The Python 2 tensorflow images will be soon deprecated and may not be supported for newer upcoming versions of the tensorflow images.
Please set the argument "py_version='py3'" to use the Python 3 tensorflow image"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SageMaker currently do not support TensorFlow 2.0 yet (neither py2 or py3). But it will be available with SageMaker soon.

As regard with Python versions. For the current supporting TensorFlow versions, py2 is supported, however, after Jan. 1, 2020, all future framework versions will not support py2 anymore.